# Visual Studio 2013 C++ Hello World Program Unexpected Debug Result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

First of all, sorry if the title is not very well chosen, but I don't know how to deal with this code showing something strange when compiled as C using Visual Studio 2013.

The code is:

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello World!", "Note", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

And, the result is :
[image]

I have MS Visual Studio 2013 Original Genuine from MSDN.
Also, I'm not Chinese. The interface of IDE is in English.

Comment: How did this even compile? Wide strings and narrow strings are not compatible types. Give winapi functions wide strings.

Comment: I copy-pasted this code (without the stdafx.h header) from a tutorial (I will give the link if needed). I tried to compile it but I got an error c1010. I, then, added that header, and it compiled successfully.

Comment: `stdafx.h` is also supposed to be the first header included, so I'm not sure how that compiled as well. Of course using precompiled headers is extremely pointless for a hello world application. The tutorial probably also didn't have `UNICODE` defined, which is a very bad thing when working with the winapi.

Comment: I, too, thought about UNICODE. Thanks for reply. I'll stick to other tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you got that to compile but you're most likely in the wrong character set for that project.

Try:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World!", L"Note", MB_OK);
```

If you're not intending to work in that character set you should change it as well.
Right-click on the project and go to Properties.
Configuration.
General.
Character set.